# how to extend belong_to functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a gem and I want part of its functionality to extend `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo` but I cannot figure out how to do it

so basically user should be able to specify:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users, foo: true
end
```

anyone know how to do it ??

This wont work:

```
module Mygem
  module BelongsToFoo

    def valid_options
      super + [:foo]
    end

    #... other functionality
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo
  extend MyGem::BelongsToFoo
end
```

console

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo.valid_options.include? :foo
#=> false   ... :(

Event
ArgumentError: Unknown key: foo
```

[belongs_to source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5c4274a34d6815415111369d09e6249ccf588f1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb)

=============================================================================
**Update**

flowing [delwyns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362678/473040) I tried to have a another look on my code and he is right it should be included however `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo` has a variable `valid_options` as well.

so I can do

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo.new(:a, :b, :c).valid_options.include? :foo
# => true
```

but also

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo.valid_options.include? :foo
# => true
```

so it should really look like this

```
module MyGem
  module BelongsToFoo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      self.valid_options += [:foo]
    end

    def valid_options
      super + [:foo]
    end

    def define_callbacks(model, reflection)
      # this wont get executed
      add_foo_callbacks(model, reflection)# if options[:foo]
      super
    end

    def add_foo_callbacks(model, reflection)
      # therefore this wont either 
    end
  end
end
```

Even if I try this

```
module MyGem
  module BelongsToFoo

    def define_callbacks(model, reflection)
      raise "dobugging"
    end
  end
end
```

nothing will happen, Rails completely ignore my method override

So yes I can define my own option, however they do nothing :(  any suggestions ?

Comment: Btw, I tried several different ways with`include` and `prepend` ...no success

Comment: Can you try `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo.ancestors` to see whether your module is included at all or if it's just in wrong place in the method lookup chain?

Comment: May I ask why do you need such functionality?

Comment: I was writing a gem, that was giving you capability to do two types of `touch`. Regular touch to touch `updated_at` and touch_cache to touch column provided by gems functionality `cached_at` so `belongs_to :foo, touch: true, touch_cache: true` ... yet I know i can specify `belongs_to :foo, touch: :cached_at`, or extend the functionality of `touch` instance method, still I was curious how to extend association methods like `belongs_to`

Comment: Gregates thank you for you tip, I will try that for further  debbuging :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built in approach for extending association proxies, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users, :extend => MyGem::SpecialTouch
end

module MyGem
  module SpecialTouch
    def touch
      # do the magic
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could of course override or alias chain `belongs_to` so that it pops your `:foo` option from options hash, converts it to proper `:extend => ...` and (really or effectively) calls `belongs_to`.

Comment: It's not quite the whole solution I was hoping for but you gave me an idea how enforce belongs to to accept extra parameters, and that what I was looking for hole time :) ... so thx... accepted

Comment: Good to hear it helped.

Answer (score 2):

valid_options is an instance method so you need to use include instead of extend.

```
module MyGem
  def valid_options
    super + [:foo]
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo
  include ::MyGem
end

relation = ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BelongsTo.new(:a, :b, :c)
relation.valid_options.include? :foo
#=> true
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. 8 years later I think this might be what I was looking for (rails 5.2), but when I dump it in config/initializers it seems to be loading after my models so it's not firing. Any idea where this can go to fire first?